# Include Github Project into Android Studio 2 project without jar or dependency

Tags: java, android, github, jar, sdk

i have found this sdk: [is24-restapi-java](https://github.com/ImmobilienScout24/restapi-java-sdk)
and i want to import it into my android studio project for further use. 
But i can't find a way to include it.

I did some searching through the github project i cannot find a simple jar or dependency that i can include into my project and all advances to generate a jar or something failed.

Can anyone give me a guid or something to include this sdk into my project or am i using the wrong approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Goto File -> New -> Import Module.
- Source Directory -> Browse the project path
- Specify the Module Name – it is used for internal project reference.
- Let Android Studio build the project.
- Open build.gradle (Module:app) file.
- Add the following line with your module name in place of “projectName” in the dependencies block:

  ```
   compile project(':projectName')
  ```

  After this Android Studio would start saying “gradle files have changed since last project sync”, press the “sync now” link to start a sync.