# Android modifiy file from compile

Tags: android, jar, dependency-management

I need to edit some code from this project https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner before this i use it with `compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'` and it work but now i need to modify and Android Studio say "Read Only" how to import this project/libraries for editing and build my app? 
I have tried some function like:

[Include Github Project into Android Studio 2 project without jar or dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41822842/include-github-project-into-android-studio-2-project-without-jar-or-dependency)

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html

But i have always 10.000 errors and not working nothing, how to generate this jar file because zip from github not have jar or similar file for importing, only project app.

Ex:

If try yo import module i have this error:

```
Error:(12, 0) Could not get unknown property `'libraries' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDe‌​pendencyHandler. dependencies { compile libraries.support_v4 }`
```

If comment this line //compile libraries.support_v4 i have another error:

```
Error:Cause: compileSdkVersion is not specified.
```

If add this in build.grandle of core,zxing and zbar:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

i have another error:

```
Error:(31, 0) Could not get unknown property 'libraries' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
<a href="openFile:\zbar\build.gradle">Open File</a>

 compile libraries.barcodescanner_core
```

Comment: You can download the code yourself, and compile the sources. I highly doubt you have thousands of errors. Please include some in the question

Comment: If try yo import module i have this error:
Error:(12, 0) Could not get unknown property 'libraries' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
dependencies {
    compile libraries.support_v4
}

Comment: Well, where is `libraries` defined?

Comment: For what it's worth, Zxing is a very difficult library to include in any project. My suggestion would be to use that whole project from Github, then replace the "UI" portions of it with your own.

Comment: Yes but the problem is not include but the code

When try to activate the flash on Samsung S5 with Android 6 it not work, now i have see the code:
parameters.setFlashMode("torch");

but zxing use :

Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH,
Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);

with TORCH and ON it work =)

So i need add parameters.setFlashMode("on"); when try to active the flash!